# Friends can hear my device audio when using Discord

Tags: kubuntu

I am getting this issue from past couple week that whenever I am using Discord my friends can hear my device audio like spotify music etc through my microphone. How to resolve this issue?
Device Description :
Device : Asus R542 U Laptop
OS : Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you use headphones or a headset? Whats the input and whtas the putput device? How are they connected?

Comment: The tag "kubuntu" is not correct, please change the tag.